# Is there a way to substitute a value in a formula using a UserForm?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very long formula in columns I2:HM13 that contains values that need to change depending on what department uses the worksheet and these values may change over the course of the year. This formula repeats in all cells within the stated range with only the reference column/row changing. I would like to create a UserForm were the end user can input the values specific to their department in textboxes and click a commandbutton and the values in the textboxes get inserted into the formula.

I have tried some find and replace codes, but nothing I have tried has work at all. Below is the formula I am trying to modify.

`=IF($H2="No","",IF(($B2-I$1)<100,"",IF(((($B2-I$1)*$C2)*1000000)<260000000000,"",IF(((I$1*$C2)*1000000)<330000000000,"",IF(AND(($B2-I$1)>=200,($B2-I$1)<=800,((($B2-I$1)*$C2)*1000000)>=620000000000,((($B2-I$1)*$C2)*1000000)<=920000000000,I$1>=375,I$1<=420,((I$1*$C2)*1000000)>=680000000000,((I$1*$C2)*1000000)<=790000000000,$C2>=1300,$C2<=2100),1)))))`

The above is a small portion of the formula of interest. The values I am trying to changed based on the textbox inputs are all the values after the less than, less than or equal to, greater than, or greater than or equal to symbols.

For example in textbox 1 the user inputs 150, 150 would then replace all "100" in the formula. If the user inputs 270000000000 in textbox 2, all the "260000000000" would be replaced with 270000000000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this solution to my question:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("I2:HM2")
cell.Formula = Replace(cell.Formula, "100,", TextBox4.Value + ",")
cell.Formula = Replace(cell.Formula, "260000000000,", TextBox5.Value + ",")
Next cell
End Sub
```

I would need to repeat this format for all the values I would want to change per department.

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach would be to create sheet-scoped names which you then use in your formulas: your userform can then change the "refersto" values for those names to the user-supplied values.

Eg:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Names("FOO").RefersTo = txtName1.Value
    .Names("BAR").RefersTo = txtName2.Value
End With
```

On your sheet:

```
=FOO/BAR
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. But, I am getting a compiling error when I use the above code. I amended the names to fit my worksheet, but still doesn't work. I found a way that works using cell.forumla = Replace function though.  Thanks again for your help.